# Renaming a file in C# and excluding the extension of the file

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
FileInfo currentFile = new FileInfo("c:\\Blue_ 327 132.pdf"); 
string fileNameFromDB = "c:\\Blue 327 _132.pdf"; 
string newFileName = fileNameFromDB + currentFile.Extension; 
currentFile.MoveTo(newFileName);
```

I need rename it with new filenamefromDB

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Orange_  325_  131.pdf
```

Since I'm using system.io.path but the files are present under C;\Uploads\..

What if I have do looping for more than one files and directory path varies every time?

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean by this - but look at the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) class for getting different bits of the filename...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To rename a single file

```
FileInfo currentFile = new FileInfo("c:\\Blue_ 327 132.pdf");
currentFile.MoveTo(currentFile.Directory.FullName + "\\" + newName);
```

where newName is your new name without path. For example, "new.pdf"

If you need to keep old file extension

```
FileInfo currentFile = new FileInfo("c:\\Blue_ 327 132.pdf");
currentFile.MoveTo(currentFile.Directory.FullName + "\\" + newName + currentFile.Extension);
```

To rename multiple files

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\temp\\"); 
FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles();
foreach(FileInfo f in infos)
{
    File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.ToString().Replace("abc_","");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation of the function [System.IO.File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx), "move" the file to a new name.

```
System.IO.File.Move(OldNameFullPath,NewNameFullPath);
```

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the original question.